# boolean operators over multiple elements

Tags: haskell

I know one can do:

```
any (>3) [1,2,3,4,5]
```

but what is the elegant way of implementing:

```
any and[(>3),(<5)] [1,2,3,4,5]
```

or

```
all or[(<2),(>4)] [1,2,3,4,5]
```

etc?

Comment: Your examples aren't type correct. What do you mean by `any and ...`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe you'd like to check whether there are any elements that are both `(<5)` and `(>3)`.

You can do that this way:

```
any (\x -> x > 3 && x < 5) [1..5]
```

and your the other one can be done by

```
any (\x -> x < 2 || x > 4) [1..5]
```

But maybe it would be more fun to define `&&` and `||` to work on functions:

```
infixr 3 &&&
infixr 3 |||

(&&&) :: (a -> Bool) -> (a -> Bool) -> (a -> Bool)
(f &&& g) x = f x && g x

(|||) :: (a -> Bool) -> (a -> Bool) -> (a -> Bool)
(f ||| g) x = f x || g x
```

so now we can rewrite your examples as:

```
any ((>3) &&& (<5)) [1..5]
any ((<2) ||| (>4)) [1..5]
```

Comment: If you are looking for the monad that is hidden everywhere, you can also define `(&&&)` as `liftM2 (&&)` ; )

Comment: Well, `(->) a` is a monad, but it is more generally an applicative functor, so `liftA2` is probably more appropriate here (alternatively just use `(&&) <$> (>3) <*> (<5)` directly).

Comment: @dflemstr *+1* for applicative use

Comment: Yes, I was thinking `liftA2` as I was writing `&&&` but feel that the incredibly lovely Applicative is for a later day.

Comment: It's tempting to use `foldl (const True) (&&&)` and `foldl (const False) (|||)` to generalise to lists of `a -> Bool` but I've again decided to leave that for another day.

Answer (score 6):

Your notation `and[(>3),(<5)]` can be almost directly implemented as a higher order function.  I'll call it `andP`, since `any` takes a predicate and a list of values, and we want a function that takes a list of predicates.

```
andP :: [a -> Bool] -> a -> Bool
andP ps x = all ($ x) ps
```

Now

```
andP [(>3), (<5)] x = x > 3 && x < 5
```

and you can write as in your initial request as

```
any (andP [(>3), (<5)]) [1,2,3,4,5]
```

As a side note, for this particular example, I think a clearer way would be:

```
between :: (Ord a) => a -> a -> a -> Bool
between lo hi x = lo < x && x < hi

any (between 3 5) [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Answer (score 3):

Another approach is to use `Monoid`s. `Bool` is a `Monoid` when wrapped in `All` or `Any` from `Data.Monoid`. We need that because there are two ways to combine `[Bool]` - we can either use `&&` or `||`. That's why there are the types `All :: Bool -> All` and `Any :: Bool -> Any` which are instances of `Monoid`. For example:

```
> import Data.Monoid
> getAll $ mconcat [All True, All True, All False]
False
> getAll $ mconcat [All True, All True, All True]
True
> getAny $ mconcat [Any True, Any True, Any False]
True
```

The other fact that we use is the `Monoid` instance for functions (again from `Data.Monoid`):

```
instance Monoid b => Monoid (a -> b) where
        mempty _ = mempty
        mappend f g x = f x `mappend` g x
```

Now we can append functions:

```
> :t All
All :: Bool -> All
> :t (<5)
(<5) :: (Num a, Ord a) => a -> Bool
> :t All . (<5)
All . (<5) :: (Num a, Ord a) => a -> All
> :t ((All . (<5)) <> (All . (>3)))
((All . (<5)) <> (All . (>3))) :: (Num a, Ord a) => a -> All
> getAll $ ((All . (<5)) <> (All . (>3))) 4
True
```

Generalizing this to lists of functions:

```
> getAll $ mconcat [(All. (<5)), (All . (>3))] $ 4
True
> getAll $ mconcat (map (All .) [(<5), (>3)]) $ 4
True
```

Then searching http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/ for `(a->b) -> [a] -> b` we see `foldMap :: (Foldable t, Monoid m) => (a -> m) -> t a -> m` which we can use instead of `mconcat . map`:

```
> import Data.Foldable
> getAll $ foldMap (All .) [(<5), (>3)] $ 4
True
```

And finally mapping it over a list of numbers:

```
> map (getAll . foldMap (All .) [(<5), (>3)]) $ [1..5]
[False,False,False,True,False]
> Prelude.or $ map (getAll . foldMap (All .) [(<5), (>3)]) $ [1..5]
True
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also define an operator that takes a list of predicates by employing some `Monoid` instances as follows.

```
test = any (andP [(>3),(<5)]) [1,2,3,4,5]

andP :: [a -> Bool] -> a -> Bool
andP ps = getAll . mconcat (map (All.) ps)
```