# Elegant way to combine multiple filtering functions in Haskell

Tags: haskell, filter, function-composition

Given the following filtering functions as unary predicates,

```hs
f1 :: Int -> Bool
f1 x = x > 30

f2 :: Int -> Bool
f2 x = x < 60

f3 :: Int -> Bool
f3 x = x `mod` 3 == 0
```

I'd like to filter a list of integers through all of them. Currently I'm doing something along the lines of:

```hs
filtered = filter f1 $ filter f2 $ filter f3 [1..90]
-- [33,36,39,42,45,48,51,54,57]
```

but it hardly feels like this is the most elegant solution possible; especially I don't like the multiple repetitions of `filter` and the lack of composability.

Would there be a way to compose all these predicates into one, let's name it `<?>`, so that a possible syntax would resemble something like the following?

```hs
filtered = filter (f1 <?> f2 <?> f3) [1..90]
-- [33,36,39,42,45,48,51,54,57]
```

The type signature of this hypothetical `<?>` operator would then be `(a -> Bool) -> (a -> Bool) -> (a -> Bool)` but [I wasn't able to find any such thing](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=(a%20-%3E%20Bool)%20-%3E%20(a%20-%3E%20Bool)%20-%3E%20(a%20-%3E%20Bool)) on Hoogle.

Comment: Prior art: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654042/boolean-operators-over-multiple-elements, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57414964/how-to-compose-functions-that-return-bools-to-one-function

Comment: FYI, you *do* have composability: `filtered = (filter f1 . filter f2 . filter f3) [1..90]`

Comment: @chepner for sure, but I was especially looking for something which factors the `filter` out in the expression you typed — but effectively, I didn't mention that in my question and this is already better than `filter f1 $ filter f2 $ filter f3`... even though it's only replacing `$`'s by `.`'s

Comment: You might be interested in my semigroup-based answer. The `Semigroup` instance for predicates is essentially `liftA2 (&&)`, as in your accepted answer.

Comment: This is perhaps the best motivator for the confusingly named [Heyting Algebra](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-prelude/4.1.1/docs/Data.HeytingAlgebra) data type in PureScript (I say confusingly named because one would expect `(&&)` to operate just on booleans). It has a function instance so you can simply write `filter (f1 && f2 && f3)`.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

What about this?

```hs
import Control.Applicative (liftA2)
-- given f1, f2, and f3
filtered = filter (f1 <&&> f2 <&&> f3) [1..90]
  where
    (<&&>) = liftA2 (&&)
```

Here, lifting `&&` to `Applicative` gives what you marked as `<?>`, i.e. an operator to "and" together the results of two unary predicates.

---

I initially used the name `.&&.` for the lifted operator, but [amalloy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/625403/amalloy) suggested that `<&&>` would be a better name *by analogy with the other `Functor`/`Applicative` lifted operators like `<$>`*.

Comment: I've ended up using this solution as it is the closest from what I initially envisioned, and it also doesn't need any additional package. Lastly it uses an applicative functor instead of a monad. I actually implemented the `(<&&>) = liftA2 (&&)` function directly in `Utils.hs` for convenience, but the compiler required to add typing information, which I did with `(<&&>) :: (a -> Bool) -> (a -> Bool) -> (a -> Bool)`

Answer (score 24):

```
> filter (and . sequence [f1, f2, f3]) [1..100]
[33,36,39,42,45,48,51,54,57]
```

Essentially the above works because `sequence` (on the `(->) a` monad as used above) takes a list-of-functions and returns a function-returning-a-list. E.g.

```
sequence [f, g, h] = \x -> [f x, g x, h x]
```

Post-composing with `and :: [Bool] -> Bool` gives you a single boolean result, so you can use that in `filter`.

Also, there is no shame in being point-ful:

```
> filter (\x -> f1 x && f2 x && f3 x) [1..100]
```

is only marginally longer, and arguably simpler to read.

Answer (score 9):

You can work with the [**`(&&^) :: Monad m => m Bool -> m Bool -> m Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/extra-1.7.8/docs/Control-Monad-Extra.html#v:-38--38--94-) of the [**`extra`** package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/extra):

```
import Control.Monad.Extra((&&^))

filtered = filter (f1 &&^ f2 &&^ f3) [1..90]
```

this gives us:

```
Prelude Control.Monad.Extra> filter (f1 &&^ f2 &&^ f3) [1..90]
[33,36,39,42,45,48,51,54,57]
```

The `(&&^)` function is [implemented as [src]](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/extra-1.7.8/docs/src/Control.Monad.Extra.html#%26%26%5E):

> ```
> ifM :: Monad m => m Bool -> m a -> m a -> m a
> ifM b t f = do b <- b; if b then t else f
>
> -- …
>
> (&&^) :: Monad m => m Bool -> m Bool -> m Bool
> (&&^) a b = ifM a b (pure False)
> ```

This works because a function type is a `Monad`:

> ```
> instance Monad ((->) r) where
>     f >>= k = \ r -> k (f r) r
> ```

This thus means that the `ifM` is implemented as for a function as:

> ```
> -- ifM for ((->) r)
> ifM b t f x
>     | b x = t x
>     | otherwise = f x
> ```

The `(&&^)` function thus checks if the first condition `b x` is `True`, in case it is not, it will return `False` (since `f` is `const False`, and `f x` is thus `False`). In case `b x` is `True`, it will check the next element in the chain.

Answer (score 9):

`Data.Monoid` defines a `Predicate` type that can be used to represent your functions:

```
import Data.Monoid

-- newtype Predicate t = Predicate { getPredicate :: t -> Bool }
p1 :: Predicate Int
p1 x = Predicate $ x > 30

p2 :: Predicate Int
p2 x = Predicate $ x < 60

p3 :: Predicate Int
p3 x = Predicate $ x `mod` 3 == 0
```

`Predicate` has a `Semigroup` instance that combines two predicates into one that is satisfied if *both* input predicates are satisfied.

```
-- instance Semigroup (Predicate a) where
-- Predicate p <> Predicate q = Predicate $ \a -> p a && q a

filtered = filter (getPredicate (p1 <> p2 <> p3)) [1..90]
```

It's unfortunate that you need to unwrap the combined predicates before you can use them with `filter`. You might define your own `filterP` function and use that in place of `filter`:

```
filterP :: Predicate t  -> [t] -> [t]
filterP = filter . getPredicate

filtered = filterP (p1 <> p2 <> p3) [1..90]
```

---

There is also a `Monoid` instance (with the identity being a predicate that always returns `True`), which you could use like

```
filtered = filter (getPredicate (mconcat [p1, p2, p3]))
```

which again you could re-factor to something like

```
filterByAll = filter . getPredicate . mconcat

filtered = filterByAll [p1, p2, p3] [1..90]
```

Answer (score 8):

We need a way to use a function like `and` to combinate predicates instead of just boolean values.

A lazy way consists in asking [Hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org/) for a type signature like `Functor f => ([b]-> b) -> [f b] -> f b`, where f is presumably something like `Int ->`.
Meet library function [cotraverse](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/distributive-0.6.2/docs/Data-Distributive.html#v:cotraverse).

It seems to work fine:

```
 λ> 
 λ> f1 x = x > 30
 λ> f2 x = x < 60
 λ> f3 x = (mod x 3) == 0
 λ> 
 λ> import Data.Distributive (cotraverse)
 λ> :t cotraverse
 cotraverse
  :: (Distributive g, Functor f) => (f a -> b) -> f (g a) -> g b
 λ> 
 λ> filter  ( cotraverse and [f1,f2,f3] )  [1..90]
 [33,36,39,42,45,48,51,54,57]
 λ>
```

Checking:

```
 λ> 
 λ> filter  (\x -> and (map ($ x) [f1,f2,f3]))  [1..90]
 [33,36,39,42,45,48,51,54,57]
 λ>
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are pretty good, but I'll give the way that I like to combine functions, that's pretty compact.
I'm a big fan of using the lift functions from Control.Monad

```
filter $ liftM2 (&&) f1 f2
```

liftM2 works by promoting the (&&) function to a monad and taking f1 and f2 as arguments.

I know that there's a function called liftM3, but I'm not sure if it would work in this context.

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:liftM3

Comment: This is essentially what the accepted answer suggests, except using a monadic lift instead of an applicative one. Is there any specific advantage of using a monad versus an applicative in this case?

Comment: Also, `liftM3` would definitely work but lacks the flexibility of using `liftM2` to produce the lifted infix operator which can then be composed e.g. `f1 <&&> f2 <&&> f3 <&&> f4 ...`

Comment: I still can't believe how this kind of answer is not eligible for deletion :)

Comment: @Jivan no. The `liftMn` are basically obsolete since `Applicative` is a superclass of `Monad`.

Comment: @Jivan for `liftM3` to work you'd have to supply it with a ternary `&&`, but `&&` is binary. so it is actually `filter $ liftM2 (&&) (liftM2 (&&) f1 f2) f3`.