# Filtering a list of elements by a list of filters

Tags: list, haskell, filtering

I was thinking how I could make it so that if I have a list of elements `[1, 2, ... n]`, and a list of filters such as `[(>3), (<4), ...]`, it would return the list of elements that have passed every filter.

Been trying this for a while and what I got so far is:

```
filt :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
filt f xs = filter f xs
```

This function is supposed to get a filter and a list of elements and return the list of elements that have passed one single filter.

And then,

```
filters :: [a] -> ([a] -> Bool) -> [a]
filters xs ps = (\p -> filt p xs) ps
```

which not only gives me error, but I also don't know if I'm doing it correctly. (I'm trying to have *each* filter of the filter list be an argument for the `filt` function, along with the list of elements.

New to Haskell, so any tips and tricks you guys wanna give me are highly appreciated!

Comment: Recent prior art (with pointers to more prior art): [SO_q64452181](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64452181/elegant-way-to-combine-multiple-filtering-functions-in-haskell)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> and a list of filters such as `[(>3), (<4), ...]`

The signature is incorrect. This is a list of function `a -> Bool`, so you should use:

```
filters :: [a] -> [a -> Bool] -> [a]
```

This will however not be sufficient. You need to turn this into a filter that checks if *all* the predicates are satisfied. We can do by using [**`all :: Foldable f => (b -> Bool) -> f b -> Bool`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:all). Here the `b` for the `all` function is a function `a -> Bool`, and thus the type of the function `(b -> Bool)` is `(a -> Bool) -> Bool`. We do this by *calling* each function on that element:

```
filters :: [a] -> [a -> Bool] -> [a]
filters xs fs = filter (\x -> all ($ x) fs) xs
```

we can further generalize the signature to:

```
filters :: Foldable f => [a] -> f (a -> Bool) -> [a]
filters xs fs = filter (\x -> all ($ x) fs) xs
```

Answer (score 2):

Chaining the filters one after another,

```
filters :: [a] -> [a -> Bool] -> [a]
filters xs ps  =  foldr (\p r -> filter p r) xs ps
```

or, shorter,

```
filters :: [a] -> [a -> Bool] -> [a]
filters  =  foldr filter
```

Or we can use `foldl' (flip filter)`, which pushes the list through filters in the left-to-right order.