# Combining multiple functions to use with `filter`

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I have two functions that I would like to combine to use with `filter` to filter a list of `Item`s.

Here's a minimal example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```hs
data Item = Item { itemName :: String, itemSize :: Int }

hasName :: String -> Item -> Bool
hasName name i
  | itemName i == name = True
  | otherwise = False

hasSize :: Int -> Item -> Bool
hasSize size i
  | itemSize i == size = True
  | otherwise = False
```

The only solution I know to filter items that have "This" `name` and `size` 42 is to call filter *twice*:

```hs
items = [Item "This" 2, Item "That" 42, Item "This" 42, Item "No" 9]
filter (hasName "This") $ filter (hasSize 42) items
```

However, I was wondering if there's some way to "combine" those two together and call `filter` just once.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lambda:

```
filter (\i -> hasName "This" i && hasSize 42 i) items
```

Alternatively, you can define your own auxiliary predicate function:

```
let condition i = hasName "This" i && hasSize 42 i
in filter condition items
```

More advanced alternatives exist, but (IMO) are less readable:

```
filter (and . sequence [hasName "This", hasSize 42]) items
```

Also see: [Elegant way to combine multiple filtering functions in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64452181/elegant-way-to-combine-multiple-filtering-functions-in-haskell)

Comment: (I realized that this might be an almost duplicate after I wrote my answer. At this point I think I'll leave it there anyway, but feel free to argue otherwise.)